# libgdx game works while debugging but not on emulator

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

This site already helped me so much in the process of creating my game, but now I'm kind of stuck, so I hope someone can help me.

I am currently trying to create a game in android studios with libgdx. It is a pretty simple jump and run game with pits and obstacles. The User has three lives, presented as three heart shaped textures. 
When the player collides with one of the obstacles, one of the hearts is supposed to turn from filled to empty.
The problem is: It works perfectly fine while debugging, but when I run it on my android tablet it doesn't. It doesn't change just ONE heart to empty, but keeps on changing ALL hearts to empty until my GameOverState appears.

To make it more understandable (hopefully), here's some of my code. I know that's a lot of duplicate code and not very elegant, but I'll worry about that later:

In my Playstate in the update method:

```
    private void updateObstacles(float dt) {
    //nerd == player
        if (obstacle.collides(nerd.getBounds())) {
            switch (obstacle.getType()) {
                ...
                case ConstantsGame.WOMAN_TYPE:
                    alreadChanged = false;
                    Score.updateHeart(gameManager);
                default:
               ...
            }
        }
   }
```

And in my Score class:

```
    public static void updateHeart(GameStateManager manager) {
          state = getStateOfHearts();
             if (state == 4) {
             changeHeart(true, 0);
             } else if (state == 3) {
             manager.set(new GameOverState(manager));
             } else if (state == 2) {
             changeHeart(true, 2);
             } else if (state == 1) {
             changeHeart(true, 1);
             } else {

             }    
     }

    public static int getStateOfHearts() {
        if ((!PlayState.alreadChanged && hearts.get(0) == heartEmpty) && (hearts.get(1) == heartFilled) && hearts.get(2) == heartFilled) {

            state = 1;
            PlayState.alreadChanged = true;
            return state;

        } else if ( !PlayState.alreadChanged && hearts.get(1) == heartEmpty && hearts.get(2) == heartFilled && hearts.get(0) == heartEmpty) {

            state = 2;
            PlayState.alreadChanged = true;
            return state;
        } else if (!PlayState.alreadChanged &&hearts.get(2) == heartEmpty && hearts.get(0) == heartEmpty && hearts.get(1) == heartEmpty) {

            state = 3;
            PlayState.alreadChanged = true;
            return state;
        } else {


            PlayState.alreadChanged = true;
            return state;
        }


    }
```

The changeHeart method does nothing more than change the correspondingly heart to an empty shape.
I just don't understand, why it works perfectly fine while debugging, but not in "real life".

Thank you so much in advance,

Maximiliane

Comment: As I read this the alreadChanged is set to false every time nerd collides with an obstacle. This means that every frame nerd collides he will lose hearts. So if he collides with the same obstacle for 4 frames he will run out of hearts.

Comment: yes, that sounds pretty reasonable. Do you have any idea how to overcome that issue? How can I make sure, that it only changes ONE time - regardless of the frames?
I already had the very same problem with a counter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On you obstacle class have a boolean to mark if the obstacle has been counted.

as simple as

```
....
private boolean counted;
....
public boolean isCounted(){
    return counted;
}

public void setCounted(){
    counted = true;
}
```

Then when you check for collision also check if obstacle is counted:

```
private void updateObstacles(float dt) {
//nerd == player
    if (obstacle.collides(nerd.getBounds() && !obstacle.isCounted() )) {  //check if obstacle is counted
        switch (obstacle.getType()) {
            ...
            case ConstantsGame.WOMAN_TYPE:
                alreadChanged = false;
                obstacle.setCounted(); //set obstacle as counted 
                Score.updateHeart(gameManager);
            default:
           ...
         }
      }
   }
```